# Spring 3.1.1 java based configuration issue of FreeMarkerConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using Spring 3.1.1 with Freemarker.
After I have successded to use the new concept of java based configuraion of the new spring 3.1.
Now I try to use Freemarker with it.
However,I got that exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
>   '/welcome' in servlet with name 'appServlet'
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1139)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Here is the WebConfig:

```
package com.springway.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.springway")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(FreeMarkerView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {

        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath(
                "/WEB-INF/freemarker.xml");

        return configurer;
    }
```

freemarker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">    

    <!-- freemarker config -->
    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
      <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
      <property name="freemarkerSettings">
          <props>
              <prop key="number_format">0.######</prop>
          </props>
      </property>
      <property name="freemarkerVariables">
        <map>
          <entry key="xml_escape" value-ref="fmXmlEscape"/>
        </map>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fmXmlEscape" class="freemarker.template.utility.XmlEscape"/>


    <!--

      View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
      different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.

    -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Principal user) {

return new ModelAndView("/welcome.ftl");
}
```

Comment: I've posted my answer. I hope that it'd assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling the same problem as yours. And I tried to turn on logging level "DEBUG" for "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer". I found following message:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/freemarker/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:154) ~[spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getFile(ServletContextResource.java:169) ~[spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.getTemplateLoaderForPath(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:351) [spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:304) [spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
.....`

And a wired log from Jetty:

`WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - /freemarker/`

*I don't know what going on!* So that I replaced the value of "templateLoaderPath" with another name, like "/WEB-INF/tmpl-freemarker/", then **everything is workable!!**

Next, I tried to use [ServerContext.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to test "/WEB-INF/freemarker/html.ftl". Here is the result:

```
Resource under /WEB-INF/freemarker/: null
```

My code of testing:

```java
@Inject
private ServletContext servletContext;

try {
    logger.info("Resource under /WEB-INF/freemarker/: {}", servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/freemarker/html.ftl"));
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("Exception while getResource", e);
}
```

It seems [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) can't find out the resource under "/WEB-INF/freemarker/" correctly either. But I'm not sure the object of ServletContext of Spring is as same as one on normal environment of Java Servlet.

I'm using FreeMarker 2.3.19, Springframework 3.1.1.RELEASE, and jetty-maven-plugin 7.4.5.v20110725 of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc

@ImportResource("classpath:/security-integration.xml")
@ComponentScan("com.springway")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setCache(true);
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setPrefix("");
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        return freeMarkerViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/freemarker/");
        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.setProperty("number_format", "0.######");
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
        Map variables = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();

        variables.put("xml_escape", new XmlEscape());
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerVariables(variables);
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have done wrong import

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

instead of do this

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```